# UIFont - how to get system thin font

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uifont

`UIFont` has methods to get regular font (`systemFontOfSize`) or bold font (`boldSystemFontOfSize`), but how to get a "thin system font" available through storyboard?

Passing "system-thin" to `UIFont` Contructor  doesn't work, this constructor only works for non system fonts.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You can use system font thin weight:

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 34, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
```

List of available weights for San Francisco:

```
UIFontWeightUltraLight
UIFontWeightThin
UIFontWeightLight
UIFontWeightRegular
UIFontWeightMedium
UIFontWeightSemibold
UIFontWeightBold
UIFontWeightHeavy
UIFontWeightBlack
```

[image: san francisco font weights]

**As of iOS 11,** `UIFontWeight*` was renamed to `UIFont.Weight.*`. More you can get here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont.weight.

Comment: Only for **iOS 8.2** and later , thnx

Answer (score 32):

***As of iOS 8.2***, you can now use `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(_ fontSize: CGFloat, weight weight: CGFloat)`:

`UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19, weight: UIFontWeightLight)`

iOS SDK provided constants for weights:

```
UIFontWeightUltraLight
UIFontWeightThin
UIFontWeightLight
UIFontWeightRegular
UIFontWeightMedium
UIFontWeightSemibold
UIFontWeightBold
UIFontWeightHeavy
```

Using system font is better than creating a font based on font name when you want to use system fonts since iOS can change their system fonts on iOS (like when they did with Helvetica Neue in iOS 7, and now, San Francisco in iOS 9).

***So what I would suggest is to include TTF file of the font you want as use that ttf file as custom font and use the custom font in your app.***

*This is the special reason why I don't like Apple.* ***Never*** *go what Apple say. Always do what we want.* ***Apple keep on changing*** *Default font for every OS.*

Answer (score 7):

Also if you want to keep same font size and just change weight then use from targeted element font size. For example:

```
demoLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: demoLabel.font.pointSize, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
```

with this you can keep default label font size and just change weight.

**As of iOS 11,** UIFontWeightThin was renamed to `UIFont.Weight.thin`. More you can get here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont.weight.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2 / Swift 5.0**

```
 label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)
```