# How to select system font programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I want to apply "System semibold 13.0" (this is the name of the font in storyboard) onto the header for a tableview cell group. To do that I'm using:

```
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 38)!
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

but idk what to put for the name string. I've tried entering "System Semibold" and "Semibold" but both result in an unwrapped optional crash. What do I have to put in the string to make it use "System semibold 13.0"?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771679/uifont-how-to-get-system-thin-font ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.systemFontOfSize` which is available in iOS 8.2 and later. For example:

```
someLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(38.0, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
```

[**UIFont Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize:weight:)